# Will 2x11-speed front derailleur work on 2x9 system?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, derailleur-front

mine Shimano 105 FD-5501 broke (I stripped thread for screw which holds it on braze) and I need to buy a new one. Will 2x11 speed front derailleur work with mine 2x9 system?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Some LBS might still have a 2x9 FD as new old stock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it *should* work.  I like to refer to Sheldon Brown's site because it tends to be clear and fairly technology-neutral.  It has [this to say](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/front-derailers.html#speeds):

> Pretty much any front derailer will work with any modern chain system.
>
> It is true that the cages have gotten slightly narrower to match the narrower chains used on systems with more rear sprockets, but this is rarely a problem in practice.